# What is the output vector of the convexHull function in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

C++:

> ```
> void
> convexHull(InputArray points,
>            OutputArray hull,
>            bool clockwise=false,
>            bool returnPoints=true);
> ```

The description given on `OutputArray hull` is as follows:

> `hull` – Output convex hull. It is either an integer vector of indices or vector of points. In the first case, the `hull` elements are 0-based indices of the convex hull points in the original array (since the set of convex hull points is a subset of the original point set). In the second case, `hull` elements are the convex hull points themselves.

1. So what is integer vector of indices ?
2. If I use the output array as a `vector<vector<int>>`, what do I get in it?
3. Can I print the results?

Comment: if your input is a contour with 20 points and the output is a vector with integers: 0,7,12,17 then your convex hull is the points at position 0,7,12,17 from your input vector.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your specific questions:

1. Integer vector of indices (where index starts from 0) are the indices that indicates which points from InputArray points are in the set of convex hull points.
2. You can use either a vector of integer or vector of points. In the first case, you get the indices that allow to access to the actual point given the input array of points. In the second case, you can read directly the coordinates of the points from the output array.
3. This question is not entirely clear as you don't mention where you want to print the results. Assuming that you want to show it in an image, you can draw the convex hull with polylines. Specifically (look at [cv::polylines](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaa3c25f9fb764b6bef791bf034f6e26f5) for more information):

   ```
   void cv::polylines  (
       InputOutputArray     img,
       InputArrayOfArrays   pts,
       bool                 isClosed,
       const Scalar &       color,
       int                  thickness = 1,
       int                  lineType = LINE_8,
       int                  shift = 0 
   )
   ```

   To print the coordinates of the points in the console, assuming that the output vector is a vector of integers, thus indices:

   ```
   size_t hull_size = hull.size();
   for (size_t i = 0; i < hull_size; i++)
   {
       std::cout << points[hull[i]] << std::endl;
   }
   ```

Comment: well in last question what i want is printing the indices points on the console .

Comment: for each index in outputVector: std::cout << inputContour[index] << std::endl;